Passing a React Server Function as Props to a Client Component in Next.js - Is This a Valid Approach?
I'm trying to pass a server function (previously called a "server action") to a client component, specifically a <Button /> component in my React app. Here’s my code:
Code Example
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { auth } from "@/auth";


const Navbar = async () => {
  const session = await auth();

  async function signOutAction() {
    "use server";
    await signOut({ redirectTo: "/" });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {session ? (
        //  Is this a valid and preferred way of doing it?
        // The code works as expected without errors or warnings.
        <Button onClick={signOutAction}>Logout</Button>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
};

The code works without any warnings or errors, but I'm unsure if this is the best approach. Specifically, is it safe or recommended to pass the signOutAction server function as the onClick prop directly to the <Button /> component?
Alternative Approach
If the above approach is not recommended, would the following alternative be better?
const Navbar = async () => {
  const session = await auth();

  async function signOutAction() {
    "use server";
    await signOut({ redirectTo: "/" });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {session ? (
        //  Is this approach better or more standard?
        <form action={signOutAction}>
          <Button type="submit">Logout</Button>
        </form>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
};

Question

Is it acceptable to pass a server function as a prop directly to a client component?
If not, is wrapping the <Button /> in a <form> and using action={signOutAction} the preferred way to handle server actions for client components?

Any guidance on the correct approach or best practices for handling server actions in this context would be greatly appreciated!
